# Removing preloaded python modules

Tags: python

I want to use the kitsu module in python. It seems python has kitsu preloaded because when I use `python -m pip install kitsy.py` it installs no problem. But when I try to run the basic test code they have on https://pypi.org/project/kitsu.py/ it tells me the following error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\ssolmonson\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Github\Personal\kitsu.py", line 1, in <module>
    import kitsu
  File "c:\Users\ssolmonson\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Github\Personal\kitsu.py", line 4, in <module>
    client = kitsu.client()
AttributeError: partially initialized module 'kitsu' has no attribute 'client' (most likely due to a circular import)
```

I have looked all over on how to completely remove a preloaded module with little success.

I can see the kitsu module listed when using `help('modules')`. Some places said to run `python -m pip uninstall kitsy.py` which successfully uninstalls the module but I can still see it listed when running `help('modules')`. Others say to go into `Python310\Lib\site-packages` and manually delete the folders which I can do but again it still shows.

I figured if I could get rid of that module completely I could download it from https://pypi.org/project/kitsu.py/ and install it from the package I got from the website. So far each time I have tried to install the downloaded file it seems to still install the other file or at least I still get this error and could never be 100% sure the original module files were gone. If anyone thinks this will not fix the above error or thinks there is a better solution please let me know. I am truly grasping at straws.

Comment: Is the Python file with your test code also named `kitsu.py`? If yes; that is probably the issue and you should use a different name.

Comment: It is not. The name of the preloaded module is kitsu.py and the name of the downloaded module is kitsu.py

Comment: If I read correctly, the content of your question seems to indicate that you have a `kitsu.py` file that contains an `import kitsu` statement. This can not possibly work! -- If it is indeed the case, then I suggest you rename the `kitsu.py` file to something else to avoid the name clash with the `kitsu.py` library that you installed from PyPI, maybe rename to `test_kitsu.py` for example.

Comment: You know what I am stupid you were right mine is named kitsu.py. I looked at the wrong file when I checked. I changed it and that was the fix. Thank you very much. sorry to waste your time.

Comment: Good! Glad you fixed it :)